# C#: Prevent Child Process to Lock the Caller Folder

Tags: c#, windows, process, locking

I start app1.exe which is located in the folder myFolder.

This app1.exe calls another app2.exe via Process.Start in C#.

I close app1.exe.

app2.exe tries to delete myFolder but it says it is locked because app2.exe is using it even though app2.exe isn't doing anything with myFolder.

Note: If I start app2.exe alone (by clicking .exe), I am able to delete myFolder. It only prevents me if app2.exe was started from app1.exe.

---

Is there a way to allow a separate process to delete its caller folder? Both app1.exe and app2.exe are in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `ProcessStartInfo` (`Process.StartInfo` property) involved when you start `app2`.  It may well be that `app2` is starting with `WorkingDirectory` set to the folder in which `app1` is located.  If that's the case you could either trying setting `WorkingDirectory` to somewhere else before you start `app2` or you can have `app2` change the directory after it has been started.